# Resonance hybrid and octet

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I am a student of grade 11. I am learning about resonance phenomena. I am a beginner with this and I am a bit confused about this. I wished to know whether atoms in resonance hybrid (not resonating structure) have complete octet or not. For eg in the resonance hybrid of the following resonating structure:-

[image]

If not, then does it gain stability by resonance or something else?

I request you to please help me.

Comment: Resonance with lone pair of nitrogen. Same as [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138409/effect-of-resonance-on-electron-density-in-methyl-vinyl-ether)

Comment: "Octet" starts to become a rather more fuzzy term when you start talking about delocalisation. Think about it: when you say "octet", you mean that *each atom has eight valence electrons*. Now if you can't assign every electron to a specific atom (or pair of atoms), then that starts to break down. You don't even know which atom has which electrons, let alone how many of them it has. *But*, if you really wanted to, one could very well argue that because the major resonance contributor(s) are formally octet complete, the molecule as a whole does satisfy the octet rule.

Comment: In that question, I wished to kow why oxygen, being electronegative and an element which completes it's octet by attracting electron disperses its electron density.

Comment: So, this means that a molecule would have many as electron as is required to fill up octet of every atom. But there is no guarantee of each atom having filled octet as it is senseless to talk about octet in resonance. Please confirm if this is the answer.

Comment: That's one way of putting it. I think the molecule you chose is not really the best example. The resonance form which you drew is probably the greatest contributor by quite a bit, so there isn't all that much resonance going on. Benzene is a more challenging example, and in that case, I think your summary would be quite apt.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @orthocresol do they not already all have a complete "octet" here? There seems to be a minor flaw in the understanding of OP.

Comment: @Safdar That’s kinda why I said this isn’t the best example.